# Maven compile error for compiled reference class constructor

Tags: java, maven, compilation, maven-3

I have the following setup:

- Parent POM with 3 modules
- Module Bottom with Class named ClassA, this module is like bottom layer EJB
- Module Middle with dependency to Bottom in provide scope, only this module can access to bottom, like service layer. Have class ClassB with 3 constructors, default (no params), String constructor and last Bottom layer Class param.
- Module Top like Web layer with dependency to Middle layer in compile scope. Here ClassC with new Object of ClassB with string constructor.

In eclipse all compile OK, but in command line Maven throw error.
I execute from the parent POM the command ***mvn clean compile*** and get the error below:

`class file for com.test.bottom.ClassA not found`

This error is with the module Top, web layer, by referring to ClassA which is a kind of Bottom module. The module Top, class ClassC, which has no dependence scope or any reference to Module, class ClassA.
The error is present with any parameters constructor.
I want one solution to solve in once run, maybe compilation option.

Please let me know any suggestion. Thanks

Here the explanation code. [Google Drive file](http://goo.gl/biAMXP)

---

### Parent POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.source.version>1.6</java.source.version>
        <java.target.version>1.6</java.target.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>test-bottom</module>
        <module>test-middle</module>
        <module>test-top</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

### Bottom - EJB layer

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>test-bottom</artifactId>
</project>
```

.

```
package com.test.bottom;

public class ClassA {

    public ClassA() {
    }

}
```

---

### Middle - Service layer

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>test-middle</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-bottom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

.

```
package com.test.middle;

import com.test.bottom.ClassA;

public class ClassB {

    public ClassB() {
        super();
    }

    public ClassB(String str){

    }

    public ClassB(ClassA a) {
        super();
    }

}
```

---

### Top - WEB layer

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>test-top</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-middle</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

.

```
package com.test.top;

import com.test.middle.ClassB;

public class ClassC {

    public ClassC() {
        new ClassB("a");
    }

}
```

Comment: Class in correct location `src/main/java` instead of `src/test/java` or vice versa?

Comment: This error is with the module Top, web layer, by referring to ClassA which is a kind of Bottom module. The module Top, class ClassC, which has no dependence scope or any reference to Module, class ClassA. The module Middle, ClassB, no have compilation problem, all sources path no have problems.

Comment: Why are you setting scope as provided for dependency test-bottom in test-middle's pom.xml?

Comment: I don't want direct dependency in my middle and top layer to bottom, the bottom artifact could be supplied to middle (service) like ejb jar in ear package. In the fact my real project works this way.

Answer (score 1):

From Maven page, Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism, [Dependency Scope section](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope):

> - **provided**
>     
>   This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, **and is not transitive**.

So, dependencies whose scope is set to *provided* are not transitive. In the context of your question, this means that test-top module's classes won't have visibility over any class that belongs to test-bottom module (i.e. `ClassA` class, which is an argument of `ClassB` class' constructor).

If you want to reference `ClassB` from `ClassC` class, then you need to set test-bottom as a provided dependency in test-top's `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>test-top</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-middle</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-bottom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This way, `ClassC` has *visibility* over `ClassA` and the project compiles.